# How to clear cache in OpenVZ?

Tags: centos, openvz

I have OpenVZ VPS and have problem with clearing the cache:
[image]

In OpenVZ not work `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`
[image]

How may be this cache clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a result, in order to clear the cache -> must restart VPS.

Answer (score 2):

This was [reported](https://bugzilla.openvz.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2684) on the OpenVZ bug tracker. It has been resolved as `RESOLVED WONTFIX`

From [Kir Kolyshkin](https://openvz.org/User:Kir) in the [bug report](https://bugzilla.openvz.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2684#c3) (project leader of OpenVZ):

> All containers share the same page cache (although there is per-container accounting), so to drop caches of one single container we have to check each page:
>
> 1 Whether it belongs to the container or not -- supposing we do have that information, which I am not sure of
>
> 2 Whether this page is used by other containers.
>
> So, while this is trivial on the host system, it is much less trivial for a container. And this is not a critical piece of functionality -- drop_caches is only useful for running various sorts of benchmarks.

Since your don't get your own kernel instance with OpenVZ you are prevented from running the command.

Answer (score 0):

OpenVZ don't support to clear cash.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try doing below steps -

```
sudo sh -c 'echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches'

sudo echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches

echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches

echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

If these steps doesn't work -

Get a real non-OpenVZ machine (KVM, Xen, etc) and this will work just fine. With OpenVZ, you don't get your own kernel instance and as such, are restricted from performing commands like this.